# Is there any conflict between DirectAdmin Brute force monitor and LFD?

Tags: centos, brute-force-attacks

Is there any conflict between DirectAdmin Brute force monitor and LFD?

any help appreciated.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, all BFM does is log the ips which are attacking you.

From this log you can ban the ips as you wish. In my case I am using CSF+LFD+BFM. So everytime BFM notices an unauthorized attack CSF bans the ip.

http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43202&p=219313#post219313